# Discord.js awaitMessages loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to write a loop with awaitMessages loop for a simple game on a Discord bot (discord.js).

Here is my code for this module thus far:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter2, { max: 1 })
            .then(collected2 => {
            const response2 = collected2.first();
            if (response1.author.id === Fighter1 && response2.author.id === Fighter2)
                message.channel.send(`Round #1, FIGHT!!`);
                message.channel.send(`${Fighter1.user.username} Punch, Kick, or Block?`);
                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, { max: 1 })
                .then(collected => {
                    const response = collected.first();
                    });
                    if (response.author.id === Fighter1)
                        const Move1 = response.content
                    else
                        message.channel.send(`Not your turn!`)
```

I want to make it revert to await.Messages if the else condition is met, (and not spam the 'Not your turn!' message in the process.)  Can anyone help?

Comment: When you say "and not spam the 'Not your turn!' message in the process.", do you mean you want to only send that message once, regardless of how many times people write a message when it isn't their turn?

Comment: I mean if it goes to the else clause, when it loops around the if clause won't be fulfilled until another user posts something. We don't want it spamming that message while it's waiting for another message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with discord.js but first I would remove this Promise chain and use async/await. You can always revert this later but it will make it much easier to read:

```js
// wait for first response
const collected2 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter2, { max: 1 });
const response2 = collected2.first();

if (response1.author.id === Fighter1 && response2.author.id === Fighter2) {
  await message.channel.send(`Round #1, FIGHT!!`);
}

// prompt for attack input
await message.channel.send(`${Fighter1.user.username} Punch, Kick, or Block?`);

const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, { max: 1 });
const response = collected.first();

// process attack response
if (response.author.id === Fighter1) {
  const Move1 = response.content;
}
else {
  await message.channel.send(`Not your turn!`);
}
```

Then, with a little bit of [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion) we can keep checking for the response to the attack question:

```js
// fn to process the attack response
async function waitForAttackInput(fighter) {
  // prompt for attack input
  const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, { max: 1 });
  const response = collected.first();

  // process attack response
  if (response.author.id === fighter) {
    //const Move1 = response.content;
    return response.content;
  }
  else {
    await message.channel.send(`Not your turn!`);
    waitForAttackInput(fighter);
  }
}

// wait for first response
const collected2 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter2, { max: 1 });
const response2 = collected2.first();

if (response1.author.id === Fighter1 && response2.author.id === Fighter2) {
  await message.channel.send(`Round #1, FIGHT!!`);
}


await message.channel.send(`${Fighter1.user.username} Punch, Kick, or Block?`);
    
const fighter1Response = await waitForAttackInput(Fighter1);
```

Comment: So I didn't include the first part of the code where it IDs the two Fighters.  The command to start the game is f$fight @ user1 @ user2  and then the first bit of code waits for the two named users to respond to start the match. (I've decided to intentionally only check the IDs of the user responses to confirm it is the correct two users and not bother with making sure they use the correct keywords, thus they can say anything to move on.  This moves to the loop part where it asks the two players in turn to choose, punch, kick, or block.  The two inputs will be processed with a d20 RNG script.

Comment: So most of your code is great, but I'm not getting the Move1 = response.content part.  I still have to write a module for that to process the two inputted moves (one from each player.)  It's not just posting a response message to the chosen move.  It has to use a d20 RNG to determine the response.

Comment: @Startropic1, `const Move1 = response.content;` was just copied verbatim from your original question. If you could provide some more info on what you want to do with the input from `waitForAttackInput` then I can hopefully help some more.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the `const Move1 = response.content;` part as it seems that it has no significance to you. Is this any clearer for you @Startropic1?

Comment: Oh shoot, now I remember what Move1 = response.content is for.  I'm defining the variable Move1 as whichever word the player chose, (punch, kick, or block.) Move1, (and Move2 after the 2nd player has inputted their response), is then checked with a d20 RNG.  The bot then sends back a message on the result based on the two d20 rolls. I know const is a permanent variable, but within a loop it can be redefined each time the loop is run.  So using const there should be fine as I understand it.

Comment: So there's kind of 2 checks.  The 1st check just asks both users pinged by the bot in the initial command to respond with any word, (it's only checking their IDs.)  When both IDs successfully pass that check it moves on to the actual fight part, (after giving the "Round 1, FIGHT!" message.)  Then we get to the loop for the actual fight.  It sequentially verifies a move from each player, (by ID) in the correct order. After the 2 moves, (1 from each player), it runs the d20 RNG on each & sends a response showing the result.  Rinse & repeat. 3 pt system, punch/kick = 1 pt,; block prevents pt.

Comment: const message.channel.send(`Not your turn!`); is incorrect. I guess just take out 'const' ?

Comment: Just looked at this. Yeah, that looks about right. I updated the answer but I think you've probably got it now, right?

Comment: I think I've gone wrong somewhere.  Here's the updated code:
https://pastiebin.com/601c331ec8ef1